# EF Core keeps logging to Azure Function logs, NO logging configured

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions

In my Azure Function App I included a library in which the database access layer is encapsulated (using EF Core, accessing an Oracle database).

Although I have not set-up logging, the database queries are printed in my Azure Functions logs when running the app locally. If I were to do this remotely, the logs would be sent to Application Insights, increasing log size quickly, which is not what I want.

Below is the code. Do you see any obvious mistakes? Thanks for any help and insight you can provide.
Cheers

Exerpt from Startup.cs for DI

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt.UseOracle(settings.OracleCredential));
```

DbContext.cs

```cs
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) {}

    //...
}
```

Comment: `OnConfiguring` executed only once per application for specific DbContext type. It is done for performance reason. So you will fail later with disabled logging. You have  to specify options when configuring services and remove code from `OnConfiguring`.

Comment: Allright I will do some refactoring. Still, I am unsure how the code above would be able to reach the `.LogToConsole()` extension method in the `OnConfiguring` method.

Comment: Done refactoring. I removed the `OnConfiguring` method completely and also removed the `DatabaseContext(string connString, bool doLog = false)` ctor and the `_doLog` and `_connString` fields. Still, EF Core is happily logging/printing SQL queries...

Comment: I have with the deployed app. Against my expectation, there are not  SQL queries logged when deployed to an actual (remote) Azure Functions app... Not sure I understand, why the runtime shows SQL queries in the logs when run locally..